# Setting messages.properties in a Spring Webflow unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, resources, message, spring-webflow-2

I'm using Spring Web Flow 2.0.7, and just started setting up my unit tests.  I've got my flows directory, containing the flow xml files and my messages.properties files on my classpath.

It's loading fine, but it doesn't seem to be automatically picking up the messages.properties file for the flow, and thus my validation unit tests are failing because it can't resolve a message for the given code.

Here's the relevant part of the exception:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'error_alnum_char_count_not_atleast' for locale 'en_US'.
```

This seems like a fairly common scenario, to use the codes resolved in messages.properties to generate error messages.  So...what's the recommended way to load the messages.properties file?

Comment: You're saying the messages can't be resolved in your unit tests, or within the Web Flow itself?

Answer (score 2):

I know how old this question is, but having found a solution I thought I'd post it for others:

```
Object obj = builderContext.getApplicationContext()
                .getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.MESSAGE_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME);
        obj = builderContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.MESSAGE_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME);
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof StaticMessageSource) {
            StaticMessageSource messageSource = (StaticMessageSource) obj;
            messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        }
```

The above code, placed into your configureFlowBuilderContext method, will resolve all messages to the code itself. This does not resolve your messages correctly, but will prevent the failure you listed and allow your tests to pass.

If there's a better way, I'd really be interested in hearing about it, as this is really only a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a `ValidationContext` to use inside custom web flow validators. I solved using reflection

```
protected MessageSource validationMessages;

/**
 * Creates a validationContext
 * We have to use reflection because there's no way to set
   the messageSource inside {@link MockRequestContext} otherwise
 *
 * @return {@link ValidationContext}
 * @throws IllegalAccessException
 * @throws NoSuchFieldException
 */
protected ValidationContext getValidationContext() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    final MockRequestContext requestContext = new MockRequestContext();
    requestContext.setExternalContext(context);
    final DefaultMessageContext defaultMessageContext = new DefaultMessageContext(validationMessages);
    final Field messageContextField = MockRequestContext.class.getDeclaredField("messageContext");
    final boolean accessible = messageContextField.isAccessible();
    messageContextField.setAccessible(true);
    messageContextField.set(requestContext, defaultMessageContext);
    messageContextField.setAccessible(accessible);
    return new DefaultValidationContext(requestContext, "validateInfo", mock(MappingResults.class));
}
```